# I'm using the following condition to split the input values by '-'.How to restrict the second value if the input is just 123

Tags: javascript, html

Input: 100-1000
output: $100 - $1,000

Input: 100
output: $100 - $ (Need some help here to display just $100 instead of showing $100 - $)

```
 <c:set var="priceRange" value="${fn:split(orderData.specialMarketDesiredPriceRange,'-')}"/>
    <span class="confirmation-page"><spring:theme code="sm.confirmation.desiredPrice"/></span> &nbsp;$<fmt:formatNumber type="number" value="${priceRange[0]}" /> - $<fmt:formatNumber type="number" value="${priceRange[1]}" />
```

Comment: which language you want?what is your original code to process input?

Comment: <c:if test="${not empty priceRange[1]}">                      - $<fmt:formatNumber type="number" value="${priceRange[1]}" />         </c:if> This condition works for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<c:if test="${not empty priceRange[1]}"                                     - 
- $<fmt:formatNumber type="number" value="${priceRange[1]}" />
</c:if>
```

I found a solution, The above Condition is working in my case.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is splitting input with delimiter "-".

```
<c:set var="priceRange" value="${fn:split(orderData.specialMarketDesiredPriceRange,'-')}"/>
```

So in case if input is only 100, then 'priceRange' would have only one value. So when below line is executed it is not displaying value against priceRange[1] as it doesn't have any value. Therefore your output is

```
$<fmt:formatNumber type="number" value="${priceRange[0]}" /> - $<fmt:formatNumber type="number" value="${priceRange[1]}" />
```

i.e. $100 - $.
Try to display dynamic values via looping i.e.

```
<c:forEach items="${list}" var="item">
    ${priceRange}<br>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: '<c:if test="${not empty priceRange[1]}">
- $<fmt:formatNumber type="number" value="${priceRange[1]}" />
 </c:if>' This condition working for me

Answer (score 0):

javascript code:

```
if (input.split('-').length > 1) {
    //your code
}else {
    input='$'+input;
}
```